# ORA-29259 end-of-input reached calling utl_http.get_response PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I am trying to call to a web service using the Oracle UTL_HTTP package. The call is for HTTPS Post and include `utl_http.set_wallet`.

when the DB try to execute a

```
req utl_http.req;
res utl_http.resp;
res := utl_http.get_response (req);
```

we get the Oracle error message:

```
ORA-29259 end-of-input-reached.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue you describe looks like "Using HTTPS With Webservice and Utl_http.request fails with error ORA-29259: end-of-input reached or ORA-29263: HTTP protocol error (Doc ID 1602116.1)" in the Oracle support system.

The solution is to make sure the ACL for the website or the wallet file has been enabled. So not only allow the website access through ACL but also allow access to the local filename where the wallet was located.

If you post the full code, we might be able to see more.